# Can iMac 5k be set up to change screen resolution at log in depending on user

Tags: screen, user-account, resolution

I have 2 users on iMac 5k and need each user to login at a different screen resolution (Default for one,  Looks like 2048 x 1152 for the other). Is this possible / can a script be set to run on login to set the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the display resolution can be different for each user. This is specified in System Preferences > Displays and the computer should remember these settings at login.